# Printing JSON POST Response/output to screen in Python

Tags: python, json, api, post, request

When I send a post request to this api in postman I get a response output to my post request. I just want to know how I can print this to the screen and/or parse it to use the response for further use

```
url = ("https://mysupersecretapi/123456/execute")

    headers =  {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Authorization': 'basic' , 'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8'}
    perameters = {
"inputs": {
"Container_Full": 'true',
"Container_Note": "",
"Output_Stream_Id": "1",
"Piece_Serialized": "<Container><Pieces><PieceSerialNo>"+strContainer[0]+"</PieceSerialNo> <CustomerSerialNo/><Note></Note></Pieces></Container> ",
"Qty_Is_Container_Qty": 'true',
"Quantity": 1,
"Workcenter_Key": 58368,
"Validate_Only": 'false',
"Start_New_Container": 'true'
  }
}

    plexReq = requests.post(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth, headers=headers, json=perameters)
    print(plexReq.request.headers)
    ####START HERE

    print(plexReq.status_code)
    response = requests.get(url)
    plexResponse = json.dumps(response.json)
    print(plexResponse)
```

'''

HERE IS THE OUTPUT I GET WHEN USING POSTMAN

```
{
"outputs": {
    "New_Container": null,
    "New_Serial_No": null,
    "Recorded_Master_Unit_No": null,
    "Recorded_Part_No": null,
    "Recorded_Quantity": null,
    "Recorded_Revision": null,
    "Recorded_Serial_No": null,
    "Result_Code": 5106,
    "Result_Error": true,
    "Result_Message": "Workcenter status does not allow production",
    "Validation_Failed": false
     },
     "tables": [],
    "transactionNo": "2069710"
     }
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by `Printing to the screen?`. PostMan is simply an API tool for making `API` requests and it's not a Python interpreter in order to be able to print it to the screen.

To `parse it to use the response for further use`? There is no way to parse fetched data to be used for another request. It could only be done manually in the request URL.

**Edit:**
this only applies to PostMan and can be solved if your requests are from your application, see [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/) on that.

Comment: Btw, this only applies to `PostMan` and can be solved if your requests are from your application, see [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/) on that.

Comment: So when i use the post method on that API, which is a stored procedure that records production, after the procedure executes it returns an output response containing the serial number of the container if the procedure executed properly. When i use postman it gives that output response i showed. I want to do the same in python

Comment: Consider using a library like [`urllib2` see here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/urllib2.html). Make the necessary call to the URL and it will give you the response as expected. You may also want to check the API docs of the site that you are requesting as they may also have relevant code snippets that may be of help to you.

Comment: I just checked out that link in your first comment for postman. I didnt realize they generated code snippets. That helps a lot, turns out i needed to use requests.request(“POST”, url, headers=headers, data = payload) and then print the output using print(response.text.encode(‘utf8’))       Thanks for your help I appreciate it!

Comment: @Damian_W If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more informatio